# querySelectorAll to get selected values of dropdowns

Tags: javascript

I want to use querySelectorAll to get the selected values for multiple dropdowns on my page, then print them elsewhere on the page.

I'm struggling to find the right way to do this because they all have different names ('dropDown[0]' and 'dropDown[1]' ect). I can't change the naming convention, so i need to find a way of selecting all dropdowns that have 'dropDown' in the name, then print the values separated by a comma.

This is what i've tried so far:

```
const dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll('select[name="dropDown"]')
if (!dropDowns) return
this.dropDown = dropDowns.options[dropDowns.selectedIndex].text
this.dropDown.join(', ')

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="dropDown1">Dropdown 1:</label>
  <select name="dropDown[0]" id="dropDown1" class="form-control">
    <option value="D20">Option 1</option>
    <option value="T20">Option 2</option>
    <option value="T11">Option 3</option>
    <option value="S10">Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="dropDown2">Dropdown 2:</label>
  <select name="dropDown[1]" id="dropDown2" class="form-control">
    <option value="D20">Option 1</option>
    <option value="T20">Option 2</option>
    <option value="T11">Option 3</option>
    <option value="S10">Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="dropDown"]')`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`^=` starts with selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#attribute-selectors) and then map:

```
var res = [...document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="dropDown"]')].map(sel => sel.value)
```

Like this

```js
const show = () => {
  const res = [...document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="dropDown"]')].map(sel => sel.value);
  document.getElementById("res").innerText = res.join(", ")
};
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("change", e => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("form-control") && tgt.id.startsWith("dropDown")) { show ()}
  });
  show(); // init
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dropDown1">Dropdown 1:</label>
    <select name="dropDown[0]" id="dropDown1" class="form-control">
      <option value="D20">Option 1</option>
      <option value="T20">Option 2</option>
      <option value="T11">Option 3</option>
      <option value="S10">Option 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dropDown2">Dropdown 2:</label>
    <select name="dropDown[1]" id="dropDown2" class="form-control">
      <option value="D20">Option 1</option>
      <option value="T20">Option 2</option>
      <option value="T11">Option 3</option>
      <option value="S10">Option 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<span id="res"></span>
```

Older less elegant answer:

```js
const onchange = () => {
  var res = [];
  [...document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="dropDown"]')].forEach(sel => res.push(sel.value) );
  document.getElementById("res").innerText = res.join(", ")
}
[...document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="dropDown"]')].forEach(sel => sel.addEventListener("change",onchange));  
onchange()
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="dropDown1">Dropdown 1:</label>
  <select name="dropDown[0]" id="dropDown1" class="form-control">
    <option value="D20">Option 1</option>
    <option value="T20">Option 2</option>
    <option value="T11">Option 3</option>
    <option value="S10">Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="dropDown2">Dropdown 2:</label>
  <select name="dropDown[1]" id="dropDown2" class="form-control">
    <option value="D20">Option 1</option>
    <option value="T20">Option 2</option>
    <option value="T11">Option 3</option>
    <option value="S10">Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<span id="res"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a regular expression in a selector but CSS selectors are powerful enough for your need with a "starts with" syntax inspired by regexes.

You can use a substring matching attribute selectors  : `select[name^=dropDown]`

Reads "Nodes of type `select` with an attribute `name` starting with "dropDown"

From the [formal specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings):

> **[att^=val]**
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name^="dropDown"]').forEach(function(node) {console.log(node.options[node.selectedIndex].value);});
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can do something like this as you want to select the option's values:

```js
var Container = document.querySelector('#output');

var Dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('select');


// Select All Options Values:
for ( var dropdown in Dropdowns ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < Dropdowns[dropdown].children.length; i++ ) {
    var elem = document.createElement('p');
    elem.innerHTML = Dropdowns[dropdown].children[i].value;
    Container.appendChild(elem);
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="0">Number 0</option>
  <option value="1">Number 1</option>
  <option value="2">Number 2</option>
  <option value="3">Number 3</option>
  <option value="4">Number 4</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="5">Number 5</option>
  <option value="6">Number 6</option>
  <option value="7">Number 7</option>
  <option value="8">Number 8</option>
  <option value="9">Number 9</option>
</select>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Just an example for doing this.