# Jest - test if function is called if prop is present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to write a test to see if a useEffect function inside my component is called if the correct prop is passed in.

PropDetail.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function PropDetail({ propID }) {
  
  const [propStatus, setPropStatus] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!propID) return;

    setPropStatus(propID)

  }, [propID]);

  return <p>{propStatus}</p>
}

export default PropDetail;
```

PropDetail.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

import PropDetail from '../PropDetail'

const props = {  }
describe('PropDetail', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<PropDetail {...props} />)

  describe('With no propID', () => {
    it('returns null if no propID passed in', () => {
      expect(wrapper.html()).toBe(null)
    })
  })
  describe('With propID passed in', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper.setProps({ propID: 'PROPID' })
    })
    it('Runs useEffect with propID', () => {
      expect(wrapper.setPropStatus().toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })
  })
})
```

The errors i'm getting in the console are 'Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function' and 'Received has value: undefined'.

I'm quite new to writing tests so i'm not sure if this is the right starting point or if i'm testing the wrong thing!

Comment: FWIW, useEffect only runs with mount, not shallow.

Comment: Hi, I see you are still around. Could you please attend to a [question from last year?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56949524/295783)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to test a feature of React such as `useEffect`. You'll want to test your code in a way such as 'what happens when useEffect has been called'.

You could test the value of `propStatus` upon initial rendering. Then make an update to the `propID`, then test the value of `propStatus`. Is the the value you expect or desire?

This way you're testing the actual code you wrote for correctness. When you see a change in `propStatus`, you'll also know that `useEffect` was called without directly testing that function.

You can also test for coverage by using `yarn test --coverage`.